# Power BI embedded Q&A events do not fire. Is it a bug?

Tags: javascript, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I am trying to embed Power BI Q&A into my webpage, using official sample from Microsoft:
https://microsoft.github.io/PowerBI-JavaScript/demo/v2-demo/index.html

There is a code that is supposed to define handler for the event that has to be fired after embedded Q&A loading.

```
// Embed the QNA and display it within the div container.
var qna = powerbi.embed(qnaContainer, config);

// qna.off removes a given event handler if it exists.
qna.off("loaded");

// qna.on will add an event handler which prints to Log window.
qna.on("loaded", function(event) {
    Log.logText("QNA loaded event");
    Log.log(event.detail);
});
```

I tried to run the sample in IE11, Chrome and Firefox, but the Log frame is always empty after report visual is loaded.

How to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Embedded Q&A fires a `visualRendered` event whenever the query changes and\or the visual result is finished render..

`loaded` is currently not fired, this will probably be fixed in a few weeks.
The sample app (http://aka.ms/pbijs) is updated to show this.

Comment: I know about `visualRendered`, tried it, but it does not fire too. Do you have an example available online where this event works?